# CausesValidation=false Is Not Clearing Data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I generally use `CausesValidation=false` in my web forms and it works, but it does not work on the form below.  If I enter some data and then click the RESET button, all of the required fields (*) will disappear; however, it will not clear the info in the textboxes or the radio button.  I tried adding Javascript `OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;"` and still it did not work.  I checked and rechecked my script, and I researched online but I could not find a solution.  Could having two pairs of <section></section> tags within the same <panel> caused a problem?  Just curious.  I noticed my previous forms have only one pair of <section> tag in each form; this is the first time I have two sections.

```
<asp:Panel ID="submitPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="submitBTN">
<section class="bg05 well04">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Application for Enrollment</h2>
    <div class="columns">
    <div class="colLeft"><h4>Select Enrollment Type (select one):</h4></div>
    <div class="colRight">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="enrollType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="spaced" ValidationGroup="submitApp">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Full-Time">Full-Time</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Part-Time">Part-Time</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList><div class="colAdjust"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="enrollRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="enrollType" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage=" *" ForeColor="Maroon" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div class="colGeneral"><asp:Label ID="PriEmailLBL" runat="server" Text="<span class='format'>Primary email address:</span> "></asp:Label></div><div class="colGeneral1"><asp:TextBox ID="PriEmailTXTBOX" runat="server" Width="250px" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PriEmailRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="PriEmailTXTBOX" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage=" *" ForeColor="Maroon" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="PriEmailREV" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Invalid email address" ControlToValidate="PriEmailTXTBOX" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Maroon" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg02 well02">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>
    <h4 class="a">Member:</h4><br />
    <div class="colGeneral5"><asp:Label ID="CellLBL" runat="server" Text="<span style='color:White;margin-left:55px;'>Cell #:</span> "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="CellTXTBOX" runat="server" Width="150px" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CellRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CellTXTBOX" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage=" *" ForeColor="Maroon" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
    <br />
    <div class="colGeneral5"><asp:Label ID="SecEmailLBL" runat="server" Text="<span style='color:White;'>Secondary Email Address:</span> "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="SecEmailTXTBOX" runat="server" Width="300px" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SecEmailRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="SecEmailTXTBOX" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage=" *" ForeColor="Maroon" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="SecEmailREV" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Invalid email address" ControlToValidate="SecEmailTXTBOX" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="White" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></div>
    <br /><br />
 <asp:Button ID="submitBTN" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="submitBTN_Click" ValidationGroup="submitApp" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <asp:Button ID="resetBTN" runat="server" Text="RESET" OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="submitApp" />
 <asp:Label ID="messageLBL" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false">/asp:Label>
 </div>
</section>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Did you try <input type="reset" /> instead of asp:button ?

Comment: @Partha I just tried <input type="reset" /> and it is not working.  Thanks tho.

Comment: You are missing an opening '>' in the following `<asp:Label ID="messageLBL" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false">/asp:Label>`

Comment: @HashPsi The '<' is in my code; I accidentally deleted it after I pasted the script on here.

Comment: When I run the code I put in the answer, the form resets as expected. If this does not work for you, then there is something else going on in the page.

Answer (score 0):

After correcting the markup and removing `OnClientClick` for `resetBTN`, it appears to have the desired behavior (form is cleared when 'reset' is pressed):

```
<asp:Panel ID="submitPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="submitBTN">
<section class="bg05 well04">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Application for Enrollment</h2>
    <div class="columns">
    <div class="colLeft"><h4>Select Enrollment Type (select one):</h4></div>
    <div class="colRight">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="enrollType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="spaced" ValidationGroup="submitApp">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Full-Time">Full-Time</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Part-Time">Part-Time</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList><div class="colAdjust"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="enrollRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="enrollType" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage=" *" ForeColor="Maroon" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div class="colGeneral"><asp:Label ID="PriEmailLBL" runat="server" Text="<span class='format'>Primary email address:</span> "></asp:Label></div><div class="colGeneral1"><asp:TextBox ID="PriEmailTXTBOX" runat="server" Width="250px" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PriEmailRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="PriEmailTXTBOX" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage=" *" ForeColor="Maroon" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="PriEmailREV" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Invalid email address" ControlToValidate="PriEmailTXTBOX" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Maroon" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg02 well02">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>
    <h4 class="a">Member:</h4><br />
    <div class="colGeneral5"><asp:Label ID="CellLBL" runat="server" Text="<span style='color:White;margin-left:55px;'>Cell #:</span> "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="CellTXTBOX" runat="server" Width="150px" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CellRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CellTXTBOX" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage=" *" ForeColor="Maroon" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
    <br />
    <div class="colGeneral5"><asp:Label ID="SecEmailLBL" runat="server" Text="<span style='color:White;'>Secondary Email Address:</span> "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="SecEmailTXTBOX" runat="server" Width="300px" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SecEmailRFV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="SecEmailTXTBOX" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage=" *" ForeColor="Maroon" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="SecEmailREV" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Invalid email address" ControlToValidate="SecEmailTXTBOX" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="White" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitApp"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></div>
    <br /><br />
 <asp:Button ID="submitBTN" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="submitBTN_Click" ValidationGroup="submitApp" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <asp:Button ID="resetBTN" runat="server" Text="RESET" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="submitApp" />
 <asp:Label ID="messageLBL" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
 </div>
</section>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I had tried removing `OnClientClick="this.form.reset();return false;"` previously and it did not work.  Now I have just tried your script and it is not working.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything else in the page or in the master page? Do you have any   javascript error when you load the page?

Comment: No, there is no javascript error when the page loads.  I have another form that is somewhat similar like this one, using the same master page and it is working fine.  Let me check the page again.